# Using FOR for the first time

Tags: javascript

I need you to print for example:

console.log(user_id) //return 1
console.log(wallet) //return 32000

code

```js
teste = [
    RowDataPacket = {
      user_id: 1,
      registration: '37EPJ304',
      phone: '2111-0000',
      firstname: 'Nascimento',
      name: 'Matheus',
      age: 0,
      foragido: 1,
      foto: null
    },
    RowDataPacket = {
      user_id: 2,
      registration: 'TESTE',
      phone: '1111',
      firstname: 'Rangel',
      name: 'Morello',
      age: 0,
      foragido: 0,
      foto: null
    },
    RowDataPacket ={
      user_id: 3,
      registration: '17EFQ230',
      phone: '411-499',
      firstname: 'Nascimento',
      name: 'Matheus',
      age: 0,
      foragido: 1,
      foto: null
    }
  ]

teste2 = [
  RowDataPacket =  { user_id: 1, wallet: 32000, bank: 18000 },
  RowDataPacket = { user_id: 2, wallet: 1867502, bank: 451650 },
  RowDataPacket = { user_id: 3, wallet: 4000, bank: 111861 }
]

for (item of teste) {
    for (itemMoney of teste2) {
        console.log('Id: ' + item.user_id)
        console.log('Banco: ' + itemMoney.wallet)
    }
}
```

How can I do to print the values ​​of each array?

Because the way it is ...

Prints well mixed values.

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: I think the problem that you have (printing undefined values on the console?) is that you cannot mix 2 different arrays with different parameters and try to print variables out which are not defined in your example for test2 array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- You can make it like that

```
test = { "user_id": 8, "wallet": 2400, "bank": 25000 }
test2 = { "user_id": 1, "vehicle": 1, "moto": 1 }
let arr = [test, test2]
for(let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
   for(let item in arr[i]){
     if(item === "wallet" || item === "vehicle") {
        console.log(arr[i][item]);
      }
   }
}
```

- If you wants to get a text of vehicle and wallet you can make it like that

```
test = { "user_id": 8, "wallet": 2400, "bank": 25000 }
test2 = { "user_id": 1, "vehicle": 1, "moto": 1 }
let arr = [test2, test];
let txt = "";
for(let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
   for(let item in arr[i]){
     if(item === "wallet" || item === "vehicle") {
        txt += item + "= " + arr[i][item] + " ";
      }
   }
}
console.log(txt)
```

Comment: I need to print only 1 value for each of the 2 objects.

With "in" I print ALL the values ​​of the object.

Comment: How you wants to print only one value and there's two deferant properties - and i also wants to know why you are used a loop when you can just directly get the value of those 2 properties from objects like `console.log(test.wallet)
console.log(test2.vehicle)`   anyway you can create a condition like `if(item === "wallet") { console.log(test[item]) }`

Comment: this is how the loop should to be if you wants to loop through those 2 objects you can make it like that `let arr = [test, test2]; for(let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) { for(let p in arr[i]) { if(p === "vehicle" || p === "wallet") { console.log(arr[i][p]); } } } `

Comment: If you wants more help provide your code and explain what you wants to do well

Comment: I updated the answer i hope that help you

Answer (score 0):

Each iteration is pulling a different object. if you just need this code to run, this will work:

```
test = { user_id: 8, wallet: 2400, bank: 25000 };
test2 = { user_id: 1, vehicle: 1, moto: 1 };

for(const item of [test, test2]){
  console.log(item['wallet'] || item['vehicle']) // I need to return the value of wallet
  //console.log(item.vehicle) // I need to return the value of vehicle
}
```

The reason you are getting type Errors is because you are accessing properties that don't exist on objects (wallet on test2 and vehicle on test). This is not a correct solution and should be refactored, but this will get your code working.